# DB2 sql: How to generate unique ids of a certain length

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, list, db2

I'm trying to use python to generate a list of unique ids that can be used as indexes in a table on our DB2 database.  My starting input is a list of ids come from a seperate table.  I need to take this list of ids and generate a list of other ids (place inside the **formlist** variable here)  These other ids must be unique and must not already exist on the target database table (table name is below shown as **FORM_RPT**

So far what I have tried is the following:

```
import ibm_db_dbi
import ibm_db
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Gen_IDs():

    def __init__(self, mycon, opt_ids):
        """Create an ID Generator object, requires an opt_id list as argument"""

        self.mycon = mycon
        self.opt_ids = opt_ids


def gen_form(self):
    """generates unique form ids based off an option list"""
    sql = """SELECT *
    FROM FORM_RPT"""

    df = pd.read_sql(sql, self.mycon)
    formlist = list(df["FORM_RPT_ID"])
    stack = 0
    opt_list = []
    while(stack < len(self.opt_ids)):
        f = np.random.randint(1000, 9999)
        #if f in df['FORM_RPT_ID'].values:
        if formlist.count(f) > 0:
            pass

        if f in opt_list:
            pass
        else:
            opt_list.append(f)
            stack += 1

    return opt_list
```

This code is generating just fine, but to my confusion, a small portion of the generated ids are still showing as existing in the target database.  The generated ids need to be 4 digits ints.

Here is an example of how it would work:

```
optionList = [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005]
formlist = [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005]

gm = Gen_Ids(optionList)
new_form_list = gm.gen_form()
```

Currently I'm getting a returned list, but the new list sometimes will have ids that exist in my **formList** variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you generate id by using `row_number()`

```
SELECT *,row_number() over( order by (select null)) as id
    FROM FORM_RPT
```

Comment: I've ran your code snippet into an sql interpreter on its own and its giving me an error.  Can you uprovide an example of how it would tie into the code?  Maybe I just need a better context for your solution.

Comment: Replace the * with the column names and specify the order by you need. But this solutiuon will just provide unique numbers for that single query - next time the numbering will start again with 1.

Answer (score 0):

Generating unique IDs is something databases provide. There is no need to use extra coding for that.

In Db2 you can use identity columns if is only for a single table or a database sequence id you want to have it as a stand alone database object.

Why does it need to be certain length?

Comment: I'm working in provisional tables, and certain tables only have keys that are a certain length.  The length constraints are related to requirements of other departments.  So I have to maintain the status quo here.

Comment: Sounds strange to me - and 4 digits keys limit the amount of data. You could start with 1000 for you identity column but I suggest double checking the real requirements (for a good solution)

Comment: This reads like a comment to me. If the question and requirements are  unclear, perhaps that should be sorted out first.